# Communication with Smart card

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I am new to the concepts of UICC and Javacards so this question might not be coherently structured.

Anyways, i was just wondering if it is possible for a UICC to store multiple USIM communication profiles, one of which is enabled (recognized by the device and used for communication).

If so, what is the theory behind alternating between the profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, totally possible. I would even say that it is probably the best way to do it.

USIM profiles can be considered as Javacard "applications" and be downloaded, installed, switched on and off or deleted as the device owner decides to switch mobile operator. All this operations can be implemented using the GlobalPlatform security architecture (Security Domains, delegation modes, etc) enabling different roles: UICC manager, operator providing connectivity, device manufacturer, etc. It can get as complex as you need.

This is especially interesting for machine-to-machine use cases. In fact, it is being hotly discussed in telecom standardization fora (ETSI, 3GPP, GSMA, you name it).

I realize this is not a programming question but I think it is worth answering because it is a very promising application for smart card technology.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!! Upon further research on the topic based on your answers, i realised that this can be achieved by using over the air technology via https. But according to research, it states that in order to achieve this, one requires the Mobile network assistance so it can be quite difficult to implement this approach. If this correct and if so, is there any other way to achieve dynamic profile switching without the MNO assistance?

Comment: Not that I know - as far as I know, in order to load a USIM into your UICC you would need the MNO's cooperation. Since the USIM is literally the key to their network, they are understandably careful about how they distribute them: you cannot "copy" it from one physical card to other.
Once the USIM is in the UICC, I don't think you need their cooperation any longer to switch among USIMs, you just need to have the overall keys to the USIM (think of it as a normal smart card).